# Import complex XML in to Excel 2016

Tags: xml, excel, vba

:UPDATED:

I am trying to import an XML file from an online source in to Excel 2016 which is working fine but the response is limited to 200 records and I want to create a single table and populate it with data with multiple requests. The response data sample I'm working with is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Products/getRecords">
<result>
<Products>
<row no="1">
<FL val="PRODUCTID">1250447000004184129</FL>
<FL val="Product Code">
<![CDATA[
1321321321321321
]]>
</FL>
</row>
```

I have now the following VB code (with a little help from other threads) but am getting all of the values together in one cell, I cant seem to pull only the product code records into seperate rows?

```
Sub XMLfromPPTExample2()

Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xProducts As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xrow As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Col As Integer
Dim Row As Integer

Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load ("xml")
LoadOption = xlXmlLoadImportToList

Set xProducts = XDoc.DocumentElement
Set xrow = 
xProducts.SelectSingleNode("/response/result/Products/row/FL[val='Product 
Code']")

Col = 1
Row = 1

For Each xrow In xProducts.ChildNodes
 Row = 1

For Each xChild In xrow.ChildNodes
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Col, Row).Value = xChild.Text
   Row = Row + 1
Next xChild

Next xrow

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you have a jason in you xml.  A jason de-serialization would probably be better.

Comment: @jdweng - that's not json, it's a CDATA XML section.

Comment: Yes it is the xml I'm trying to load in a single column but at the moment I am getting both the FL PRODUCTID and Unit Price in the same column as the default schema created on import doesn't seem to recognise the difference After reading some other posts, It sounds like a bit of VBA code with a loop would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have got the vba code up and running to bring in the first 200 records, now i just need to build a loop in to get the rest of them!

```
Sub Tester()
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

xDoc.async = False
xDoc.validateOnParse = False

If xDoc.Load("xml") Then
' The document loaded successfully.
Else
' The document failed to load.
End If

Dim i As Integer
Dim list As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set list = xDoc.SelectNodes("//response/result/Products/row")

Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

i = 1
For Each node In list
    i = i + 1

    With Sheet1.Rows(i)
        .Cells(1).Value = GetNodeValue(node, "FL[@val=""Product Code""]")
        .Cells(2).Value = GetNodeValue(node, "FL[@val=""PRODUCTID""]")
    End With

Next node

End Sub
```